# Assign to array output of log in bash

Tags: bash

i'm very new in bash environment, so I apologise in advance if this question is obvious...

well I have this output:

```
  log:
    -68 -73 -70 -72 -74 -74 -75 -73 -79      port1
    -68 -73 -70 -72 -74 -74 -75 -73 -79      port1
    -68 -73 -70 -72 -74 -74 -75 -73 -79      port1
```

and I want to assign those measurements to an array :

```
mes_port1[1] = -68
mes_port1[2] = -73
mes_port1[3] = -70
.
.
.
mes_port1[7] = -73
```

you can see that the log is multiple lines , but it is o.k just to get the results from the last line.
also would it be a numeric values that I could do some calculations with them ?

thank's

Comment: You're probably better off looking at `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the values from the last line of the log into an array:

```
read -r -a mes_port1 < <(tail -n1 /your/file.log)
```

Then you can access the members as so:

```
> echo ${mes_port1[0]}
-68
> echo ${mes_port1[2]}
-70
> echo ${mes_port1[8]}
-79
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say: a) only last line `tail -n 1` : b) do not use "port1" for array (removed with `sed`)

```
declare -a array_name=($( command_for_output | tail -n 1 | sed 's/port1//' ))
```

or simpler:

```
array_name=($( command_for_output | tail -n 1 | sed 's/port1//' ))
```

Note that bash arrays start with index 0! So you will end up with:

```
echo ${array_name[0]}
-68
```

and so on.

Comment: great It's working. as I understand the values are numeric  ? if they are , anyone how to perform a logarithmic operation ?  i'll try this one from http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/bcfaq.html#bashlog , I can accept that the operation will be done only on positive numbers and the fact that it is not fixed-point.

Comment: There is no distinction between strings and numbers in bash. For doing arithmetic operations in BASH, use `$(( ... ))` , i.e. `$(( ${arr[0]} - ${arr[1]} ))` would subtract two numbers. Note BASH arithmetics is integer only, for floating point operations use `bc -l`: e.g. `bc -l <<< $var1/132` or `echo 1+1 | bc -l`. For logarithms: (in bc) l(x) for natural log. see `man bc`